# Manga where the protagonist fights the demon king and loses. He is then sent back in time at the request of god

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, manga, powers

In this manga the Main Character dies in the final battle and is sent back in time to redo the fight but with his consciousness intact. He works in a mine and spends all his money on health potions, becomes broke and in debt or something like that. He then figures out it was none other than the demon lord that requested he be resurrected to fight again.

It is not https://myanimelist.net/manga/74283/Tsuyokute_New_Saga

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you remember any details of the art or the appearance of the characters?

Comment: @Mango Man - If anyone correctly identifies the manga you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: *Lord of the Rings: Fellowsh* – oh, *manga*. Never mind!

Comment: How far back in time does he go? A few years, or does he return to his childhood? To confirm, you mention his consciousness; he goes back to the body he had at the time, correct? Was he in debt before, or did he try changing the past and end up in debt only because of his new behavior? Do you remember about when you read this, and about how many chapters there were? And do you remember about how far in the story he discovers the demon king's involvement in his time travel?

Answer (score 2):

Could be ***[Doom Breaker](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/1qs65a6/doom-breaker)***, a webtoon that updates on Saturdays.

From Baka-Updates:

> Zephyr is the last human fighting evil in a world abandoned by the gods. When he is killed in battle by Tartarus, the god of destruction, all hope for humanity seems lost. But Zephyr’s fate is not sealed -- the gods who find his battles entertaining have gifted him a second chance at life, as he is sent ten years into the past, back to when he was a slave instead of the most powerful human alive. Can Zephyr get his revenge against Tartarus and save the woman he loves, or is he doomed to repeat the past?

The main character gets sent back because he was able to wound the Demon Lord who wanted a rematch. He works as a slave in a mine and, he gets into a lot of debt at the beginning of the story, which all matches.

Comment: @LogicDictates Webtoons is an official licensor of comics. They're not a copyright infringing site. Their business model just consists of giving away almost every chapter, with the last 5-10 being paid exclusives.

Comment: @qazmlpok - Okay. I'm not familiar with that site.